# How can I make the reactionTime work in my while loop

Tags: java

I'm programming a project which calculates the time that it takes the user to write the answer. So I will display a question and you'll answer it. After that, I will display the time it takes for you to solve it.

But the reaction time is not working when I put the variables inside my while loop.

Here is the code:

```java
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long reactionTime = endTime - startTime;
//Q1
System.out.println("Q1");
while (true) {
    System.out.println("What is 1+1: ");
    int ans = scanner.nextInt();
    if (ans == 2) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        System.out.println(reactionTime + "ms");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("incorrect please try again");

    }
}
```

Comment: The end time should of course be taken when the correct answer has been found. What do you mean by "_But the reaction time is not working when I put the variables inside my while loop_"?

Comment: Is the reaction time expected to be the amount of time it took for the user to find the right answer or the amount of time from question prompt to answer entry?

Comment: @vsfDawg It's the amount of time it took the user to find the right answer

Comment: @maloomeister Yes, I solved my problem after looking at the answers I got from the others. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your end time and your start time are basically equal because you take both of them before the question is even asked.

To solve it, only calculate the time it took, once the answer of the user is correct.

```java
// take the start time once before the user gets to answer your question
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//Q1
System.out.println("Q1");
while (true) {
    System.out.println("What is 1+1: ");
    int ans = scanner.nextInt();
    if (ans == 2) {
        System.out.println("Correct");

        // take the end time here, only if the answer of the user is correct
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long reactionTime = endTime - startTime;

        System.out.println(reactionTime + "ms");
    } else {
        System.out.println("incorrect please try again");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Questionnaire {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int totalQuestions = 10;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
            String title = "What is 1+1: ";
            String correctAnswer = "2";
            long reactionTime = askQuestionAndGetReactionTimeMs(scan, title, correctAnswer);
            System.out.format("Reaction time: %dms\n\n", reactionTime);
        }
    }
    
    private static long askQuestionAndGetReactionTimeMs(Scanner scan, String title, String correctAnswer) {
        long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(title);
            String answer = scan.next();
            
            if(correctAnswer.equals(answer))
                return System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
            
            System.out.println("incorrect please try again")
        }
    }
}
```